# What does this structure mean?

Tags: grammar

**Whatever book resides in the pantheon of grand literature defies dictionary-free reading, unlike one of those faddish, modern commercial novels.**

This structure is beyond me.
What is the syntax here and is this a valid sentence from a grammatical point of view?
I think the subject-verb strcture is suspicious.

Comment: Was it written by a non-native speaker?

Comment: What makes you think so? Yes it was.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Whatever book resides in the pantheon of grand literature defies dictionary-free reading, unlike one of those faddish, modern commercial novels.

This is a perfectly valid and grammatical sentence, and does make perfect sense. Can you please tell where you find the problem, especially the sub-verb agreement one? Knowing this will help me answer the question from the perspective of your confusion. And what is the source of the sentence?

Anyways, still I will give an answer.

I am now breaking this sentence like the following -

```
1. A = Whatever book resides in the pantheon of grand literature.

2. B = One of those faddish, modern commercial novels.
```

Now forming the sentence using **A** and **B**, it comes down to this form -

> **A** defies dictionary-free reading, unlike **B**.

Though it's better to write this as following -

> Unlike **B**, **A** defies dictionary-free reading.

**Meaning** - **A** and **B** are not alike. **A** defies dictionary-free reading.

Does my answer address your problem area?